# What is the purpose of having a suffix for Java Primitive Data Types?

Tags: java, primitive-types

Sorry for a beginners question! I am learning Java and I'm a bit confused on one topic.

For example, I am declaring and initializing a variable as a float such as:

```
float myVariable = 9.5;
```

In some tutorials online, I see floats being declared and initalized like that, but also with a suffix such as this:

```
float myVariable = 9.5F;
```

What is the purpose of the the suffix if I am already saying "float myVariable"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java uses suffixes with these primitives types, here is a brief intro:

**float**

`float fVariable = 5.5` is by default double while `float fVariable = 5.5f` makes it float

**long**

`long lVariable = 55` here literal 55 is by default int type but `long lVariable = 55l` makes it long type.

**double**

`double dVariable = 5.5` and `double dVariable = 5.5d` are similar but here d suffix is  optional

Comment: In "float fVariable = 100", 100 is by default an integer. So, to make "float fVariable = 100" a float, do I need to do "float fVariable = 100f"?

Comment: literal 100 is int but when you assign it to a float type variable like (float fVariable = 100), value of fVariable is float (that is 100.0) but until int max value (that is 2147483647) so if you try float fVariable = 2147483648 or bigger you have to append l or L or it will not compile.

Comment: @user2521738 No. `float x = 100;` is allowed because `100` is of type `int` and a [widening conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) is automatically performed.

Answer (score 7):

Floating point literals are by default of `double` type. So, `9.5` is *double* not *float*. To make it float we append an `f` at the end.

So, in first case:

```
float myVariable = 9.5;
```

You are trying to assign a double type literal to a float type variable, which requires an explicit typecasting. The statement won't compile. You need to add a cast there:

```
float myVariable = (float) 9.5;
```

While in 2nd case:

```
float myVariable = 9.5F;
```

there is no conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So "float myVariable = 9.5;" is the same as "double myVariable = 9.5;"? (since both are double values).

Comment: `float myVariable = 9.5;` won't perform a narrowing conversion - it will fail to compile because you are trying to assign a double value to a float. (a narrowing conversion would happen, for example, if you did `myVariable += 9.5`)

Comment: @user2521738. No they are not essentially the same. The type of `myVariable` is different in both the cases.

Comment: @RussellZahniser. In Java, assignment conversion happens automatically. So, that will be fine.

Comment: `float myVariable = 9.5;` won't compile, try it.

Comment: @RohitJain: Assignment conversion [can only be widening](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

Comment: @RohitJain The narrowing conversion you linked is only for types: byte, short, and char

Comment: Ah! Crap. Mixed up everything out there. :( :(

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to compile your code?

This will not compile, because by default all floating-point literals are `doubles`

```
float myVariable = 9.5;
```

You can use explicit cast operation

```
float myVariable = (float) 9.5;
```

But it's too verbose, so thankfully the 'F' suffix was introduced:

```
float myVariable = 9.5F;
```

BTW, both UPPER ('F') and lower ('f') cases are allowed.

Comment: Uppercase 'F' is normally preferred, if only for symmetry with the 'L' suffix for longs. The `l` suffix looks too much like a `1` to be practical.

Answer (score 1):

Thought it might be worth providing an answer that cites the specification. From **[§3.10.2 Floating-Point Literals:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)**

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an
>   ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double...

In other words, `9.5` and `9.5f` are two distinct literals with different types.

- `9.5` is of type `double` and cannot be assigned to a `float` without
  explicit casting
- `9.5f` is of type `float` (and as such can obviously be
  assigned to a variable of type `float`)